# How to poll in setInterval that hits node.js route frquently

Tags: node.js, polling

In my application i need to request a route for every two seconds. I am trying to do it with setInterval all the times it is throwing errors as `cannot render unknown response object`.I need a method that can render a route frequently.

This the route that need to be rendered for every 2 seconds:

```
app.get('/output',inputController.getValues);
```

The callback for the route:

```
var getValues = function(req,res){
var msg = JSON.stringify({
  date: new Date().toString(),
});
mqttClient.publish(topic, msg, function() {
  influxClient.query('sliderValue')
  .then((rows) => {
    console.log(rows.results);
    res.render('output',{page_title:"Output",data:rows.results[0].series[0].values});
  }).catch(console.error);
});
}
exports.getValues = getValues;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Example:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);

function myCallback() {
  // Your code here
}
```

Another Example:

```
setInterval(
    function() {
       // Run your function here
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: i tried it earlier. it always throws me error as `Cannot read property render of undefined`

Comment: Your above code doesn't show you running a `setInterval` so I'm assuming you didn't hook it up to a function then run that function every 2 seconds.

Comment: @Candy check the second example.

Comment: I had a `res` object in the function so when i am doing it the first time the view renders properly from then its an unknown `res`.

Comment: Before your .catch() block, run another .then() and place a setInterval in there.

Comment: No that doesn't work. Actually every time a request had to be made so that `res` object will be worked properly.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're doing or trying to achieve. You just want to call a route every 2 seconds which you can do perfectly fine with `setInterval`. If this is a complete misunderstanding, could you please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can see the issue you're having and help attempt to solve it.